# Oracle trigger conflict with null

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, null, sqlplus

First and foremost, this is for an assignment, so most of the really cool pre-written functions you'll want to suggest, I will not be allowed to use.

I have a couple tables that all have fields

```
creation_date
created_by
last_update_date
last_updated_by
```

I need to write a trigger that fills these in for creation or updating. The problem is, these tables have null values that are problematic to me. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parts
(
pno                NUMBER,
pname              VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
qoh                NUMBER       NOT NULL,
price              NUMBER(5,2),
reorder_level      NUMBER(2),
creation_date      DATE         NOT NULL,
created_by         VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
last_update_date   DATE         NOT NULL,
last_updated_by    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT parts_PK PRIMARY KEY (pno))
```

These NOT NULL's are given to me and I'm not allowed to change them. So I'm having trouble conceptualizing this.

- If my trigger adds these values before the field is created, I can't do an INSERT INTO with those fields blank because they're NOT NULL.
- If my trigger adds these values after the field is created, I get compilation errors ORA-00903 and 00922. Invalid table name and invalid option.

I was thinking my trigger would look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pcreate
  BEFORE UPDATE on parts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    SET creation_date = SYSDATE;
    SET created_by = USER;
    SET last_update_date = SYSDATE;
    SET last_updated_by = USER;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pchange
  BEFORE UPDATE on parts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    SET last_update_date = SYSDATE;
    SET last_updated_by = USER;
END;
/
repeat for the other tables
```

I might be allowed to use UPSERT but I don't really know how that works.. Any suggestions are welcome. I'm really in this to learn so any other advice is appreciated.

EDIT:

My package that will not acknowledge the trigger is as follows. Do I need to call the trigger inside the package?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE process_orders 
AS
  PROCEDURE add_order (p_cno IN NUMBER, p_eno IN NUMBER, p_received IN DATE);
  PROCEDURE add_order_details (p_ono IN NUMBER, p_pno IN NUMBER, p_qty IN NUMBER);
  PROCEDURE ship_order (p_ono IN NUMBER, p_sdate IN DATE);
  PROCEDURE delete_order (p_ono IN NUMBER);
  FUNCTION total_emp_sales (f_eno IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
END process_orders;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY process_orders 
AS
  PROCEDURE add_order (p_cno IN NUMBER, p_eno IN NUMBER, p_received IN DATE) 
  IS
  ao_emsg       VARCHAR2(100);
  p_rec_today   DATE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT SYSDATE INTO p_rec_today FROM dual;
    IF p_received is null THEN
        INSERT INTO orders (ono, cno, eno, received)
        VALUES(order_number_seq.NEXTVAL,p_cno,p_eno,p_rec_today);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO orders (ono, cno, eno, received)
    VALUES(order_number_seq.NEXTVAL,p_cno,p_eno,p_received);
    END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ao_emsg := substr(SQLERRM,1,100);
      INSERT INTO orders_errors (ono,transaction_date,message)
      VALUES(order_number_seq.CURRVAL,SYSDATE,ao_emsg);
  END;
  --Etc. Procedures
END;
/
```

Comment: Your question originally discussed the `PARTS` table and triggers on the `PARTS` table.  Your edit discusses procedures defined on the `ORDERS` table.  Are you having problems inserting data into the `PARTS` table?  Or just the `ORDERS` table?  If you are having problems with the `PARTS` table, since you've already posted the definition of that table, can you post the code that is generating the error inserting into `PARTS`?  Can you post the complete error message and the trigger(s) that you have defined?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for your help. The assignment has 5 tables with those date and user columns, but it says "make triggers for these 3 tables", so the error was referencing one of the two tables I didn't write a trigger for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your trigger, you simply want to modify the `:new` record.  Your triggers would look something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER parts_before_insert
  BEFORE INSERT on parts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.creation_date := SYSDATE;
  :new.created_by := USER;
  :new.last_update_date := SYSDATE;
  :new.last_updated_by := USER;
END;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER parts_before_update
  BEFORE UPDATE on parts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.last_update_date := SYSDATE;
  :new.last_updated_by := USER;
END;
```

In your `INSERT` statement, you would omit these four columns and let the trigger fill in the values.  For example (obviously, your primary keys would be coming from something like a sequence rather than being hard-coded)

```
SQL>  insert into parts( pno, pname, qoh, price, reorder_level )
  2     values( 1, 'Widget', 10, 100, 75 );

1 row created.

SQL> select *
  2    from parts;

       PNO PNAME                                                     QOH
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
     PRICE REORDER_LEVEL CREATION_ CREATED_BY LAST_UPDA LAST_UPDAT
---------- ------------- --------- ---------- --------- ----------
         1 Widget                                                     10
       100            75 26-SEP-12 SCOTT      26-SEP-12 SCOTT
```

Comment: @caleb.breckon - I updated my answer with an example of an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I get an error for trying to enter a NULL value for creation_date

Comment: @caleb.breckon - What error are you getting?  What is the statement that you are executing?

Comment: I have my files separated into .sql, .pkg, and .trg. The .trg is executed inside the .sql between table creation and some baseline data entry. These INSERTS in my .sql file get created. But when i try to execute some procedures from the package that create other inserts, those ones give me a "trying to insert NULL for creation_date" error". Shouldn't my package acknowledge my triggers after they were created in the .sql?

Comment: To clarify: this exact same statement works when used right after the trigger file execution, but gives me the error when using it inside my pkg.

INSERT INTO customers (cno,cname,street,zip,phone) VALUES(c_number_seq.NEXTVAL,'Ron Swanson','342 Pawnee Avenue','20650','301-862-1820')
/

Comment: @caleb.breckon - Assuming that you are creating a trigger on `CUSTOMERS` (your question and my answer is only dealing with the `PARTS` table), assuming that the ORA-01400 error references a column that is getting populated in the trigger, and assuming that the `INSERT` statement is identical in both places, that implies that something is dropping or disabling the trigger between the time that the statement is executed successfully and the time that the statement fails.  Can you post a test case that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of executing `UPDATE` statement in triggers in your case. Just assign new values to the columns using `:new`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pchange
  BEFORE UPDATE on parts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.last_update_date = SYSDATE;
  :new.last_updated_by = USER;
END;
```